# Excel to Word - Mail Merge - Charts, Tables & name ranges covering multiple cells

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge, vba

I am trying to figure out the best way to send information from Excel to Word. I am currently using a data source created in excel (.csv) to send information to Word via mail merge. I have only figured out how to mail merge individual referenced cells and my data source has thousands of fields. I was wondering if it is possible to use mail merge or other technology to send either tables or a named ranges referencing multiple cells from Excel into Word. Ideally if I can send multiple cells at once I hopefully would not have to format each field. Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you consider copy-paste action? is it an option in your situation?

Comment: Have you considered extracting the tables/ranges from Excel as images and then mail-merging the images into Word?

Comment: @Kazimierz Jawor - I am dealing with an excel and word model template. If I used the copy and paste method I believe it will always be linked to the original spreadsheet or is there a way to change this in Word like in Excel (Data, edit links, etc.)..

Comment: @Xabier - I am interested in this method. Would you be able to send me a link to a website where I can learn more or can you describe how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: These multiple cell ranges: are we talking about a one-to-many kind of relationship. For example a list of orders for a company?

Comment: @DonDon, you can past special in different modes, not only as a linked to excel

Comment: @Cindy Meister I think so. For example a chart that notes historical and projected profit and loss numbers for multiple years for one company.

Comment: Check out the "Special Merges" at this site and tell me which comes closest to what you're thinking of: http://homepage.swissonline.ch/cindymeister/MergFram.htm

Comment: @Cindy Meister - That is an incredible website that you put together. Bravo! I am still trying to figure out what you mean by, "Create a chart for each record in Excel. Add a column to the data table and enter the name of the appropriate chart for each record. Use this merge field in LINK field in the mail merge document."

Comment: As mentioned in the other discussion: I'm not sure we mean the same thing with "chart"...

Comment: @Cindy Meister - By chart, I meant a table or a group of cells under a named range.

Comment: Right. Then you do NOT want the section on charts on my website as that's not applicable. You want the "multiple items" part. Assuming the goal is a one-to-many listing of items for each merge entry.

Comment: @Cindy Meister - In the section "Group multiple items for a single condition", The sample file in number #1 does not lead the user to the file. Also, would number 3 or 4 work with excel or only Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use DocVariables for this.

```
Sub PushToWord()

Dim objWord As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim bkmk As Word.Bookmark
sWdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , , , False)
Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open(sWdFileName)
'On Error Resume Next

objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("BrokerFirstName").Value = Range("BrokerFirstName").Value
objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("BrokerLastName").Value = Range("BrokerLastName").Value
objWord.ActiveDocument.variables("Ryan").Value = Range("Ryan").Value


objWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

'On Error Resume Next
objWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Run the code from Excel.

```
In the Excel VBA Editor: Tools->References->Microsoft Word x

Insert->Field->Category:DocumentAutomation->Field Names:DocVariable->Field Codes Button-> Then enter the name of the variable.
```